# Render form outside the modules Yii

Tags: php

I want to renderpartial a form outside my module, can you tell me how?
This is the location of my module.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\protected\modules\employees\views\employees\_form4.php
```

the location of the form that I want to render is:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\protected\views\empLicense\_form.php
```

now this is my code:
`_form4.php` Code

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('../../../views/empLicense/_form')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
$this->renderPartial("//empLicense_form");
```

when using `//`, view is searched under application's view path.